# How to find all possible combinations given in a list, given there should exist a common element?

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have the following list:

```
l3=[['a','b'],['a','e'],['e','g'],['f','h']]
```

I can easily generate all the combination of 3 element using the list

But now I want to find the combination of all the lists which have a common element between them. For instance:
one possible outcome can be ['a','e','b'] (Since between list [a,b] and [a,e]; there is common element'a')
However any combination like [a,e,f,h] is not allowed since there are no common elemnts betwee list [a.e] and [f,h].

Comment: So, basically you consider the pairs edges in a graph and are looking for a random sample of nodes from a connected subgraph?

Comment: @tobias_k yeah you can put it that way...

Answer (score 0):

Sets are easier to work with in this case:

```
[list(a | b) for a, b in itertools.combinations(map(set, l3), 2) if a & b]
# => [['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'e', 'g']]
```

Turn each sublist into a set, then match each set against every other using `combinations`. If there is a non-empty intersection, yield the union of the two sets (as a list, so you can't see me using set magic :P )

Comment: Yah it worked. Thanks for the answer. Sorry can't upvote because of site's policy.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you are basically trying to get a random sample of nodes from connected components in a graph. This may be overkill, but you could use the [Union-Find algorithm / Disjoint-Set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to quickly find the "connected components".

```
from collections import defaultdict
leaders = defaultdict(lambda: None)

def find(x):
    l = leaders[x]
    if l is not None:
        l = find(l)
        leaders[x] = l
        return l
    return x

l3 = [['a','b'],['a','e'],['e','g'],['f','h']]
for x,y in l3:
    lx, ly = find(x), find(y)
    if lx != ly:
        leaders[lx] = ly
groups = defaultdict(set)
for x in leaders:
    groups[find(x)].add(x)
groups = list(groups.values())
print(groups)
# [{'a', 'g', 'e', 'b'}, {'h', 'f'}]
```

Then just randomly choose one of those and get a sample from it. Optionally, use different probabilities for the different groups based on the number of elements in them. (Left as an excercise to the interested reader.)

```
import random
s = random.sample(random.choice(groups), 2)
print(s)
```

Note: This may also return samples that are not directly connected, e.g. `[a, g]`. Not sure wheter this is wanted or not.